How to use ESLint 9.11 with PHP?
Previously, I used .eslintrc.json setting with ESLint, using the eslint-plugin-html and the eslint-plugin-php-markup plugins to work through the PHP code. Here's my previous setting:
{
  "env": {
    "browser": true,
    "es2021": true
  },
  "extends": "eslint:recommended",
  "overrides": [
  ],
  "parserOptions": {
    "ecmaVersion": "latest"
  },
  "rules": {
    "no-redeclare": "warn",
    "no-unused-vars": "warn",
    "no-redeclare": "warn",
    "no-extra-semi": "off",
    "no-empty": "off",
    "no-inner-declarations": "off",
    "no-useless-escape": "off"
  },
  "plugins": [ "html", "php-markup" ],
  "settings": {
    "php": {
      "php-extensions": [ ".php" ],
      "markup-replacement": { "php": "", "=": "0" },
      "keep-eol": false,
      "remove-whitespace": false,
      "remove-empty-line": false,
      "remove-php-lint": false
    }
  }
}

Now that I've upgraded to ESLint 9.11, the setting was automatically migrated to eslint.config.mjs, here's my new settings:
import html from "eslint-plugin-html";
import phpMarkup from "eslint-plugin-php-markup";
import globals from "globals";
import path from "node:path";
import { fileURLToPath } from "node:url";
import js from "@eslint/js";
import { FlatCompat } from "@eslint/eslintrc";

const __filename = fileURLToPath(import.meta.url);
const __dirname = path.dirname(__filename);
const compat = new FlatCompat({
    baseDirectory: __dirname,
    recommendedConfig: js.configs.recommended,
    allConfig: js.configs.all
});

export default [...compat.extends("eslint:recommended"), {
    plugins: {
        html,
        "php-markup": phpMarkup,
    },

    files: ["**/*.{php,js,html,htm}"],

    languageOptions: {
        globals: {
            ...globals.browser,
        },

        ecmaVersion: "latest",
        sourceType: "script",
    },

    settings: {
        "php-markup": {
            "php-extensions": [".php"],

            "markup-replacement": {
                php: "",
                "=": "0",
            },

            "keep-eol": false,
            "remove-whitespace": false,
            "remove-empty-line": false,
            "remove-php-lint": false,
        },
    },

    rules: {
        "no-redeclare": "warn",
        "no-unused-vars": "warn",
        "no-extra-semi": "off",
        "no-empty": "off",
        "no-inner-declarations": "off",
        "no-useless-escape": "off",
    },
}];

However, I can no longer lint my PHP files anymore. With the existing settings, ESLint just throw up valid JS-embedded PHP constructs as syntax errors.
How can I make PHP work with ESLint 9.11?
